# PHP Codeigniter 3 Query Builder Get Result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am very very new to PHP (and Codeigniter as well). I am trying to build a small web app with codeigniter and I have the following the situation.

- I am using Codeigniter 3 & Bootstrap 3
- I am using Codeigniter's Query Builder Class to delete items from the database
- I have two table in the database named **movie** & **category**
- **movie** has a column named *category_id* with a foreign key reference to the **category** table's primary key *category_id* with constraints "**ON DELETE RESTRICT**"

Now if I want to delete such a category which has a reference to the **movie** table, then the DELETE operation will fail which is normal. But I am having issue to  handle such error in PHP.

Here is my PHP Codeigniter code to delete a query.

```
public function deleteCategory()
  {
    if (isset($_POST['cat-id'])) {
      $result = $this->db->delete('category', array('category_id' => $_POST['cat-id']));
      if ($result) {
        var_dump("Deleted Successfully");
      } else {
        var_dump("Failed To Delete");
      }
    }
  }
```

This code works fine when there is no foreign key constraints. But it shows the following error when there is a foreign key constrains

> Error Number: 1451
>
> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`demoapp`.`movie`, CONSTRAINT `server_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
> (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`))
>
> DELETE FROM `category` WHERE `category_id` = '1'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/demoapp/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

I followed several suggestions from other stackoverflow's answer but it didn't work for me.

So, my question is how to handle this situation in Codeigniter? Also it will be helpful to know how to deal with Codeigniter's other query build classes error as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a very very simple soultion after searching the error code.

I just set **'db_debug'** to **FALSE** in the **database.php** file located at **config** folder and the error was gone. Also the failed message was showing on the screen.